# How to send location using sms? (fused location api)

Tags: java, android-studio, smsmanager, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm currently making an app for school.. my app functions specifically for sending users most accurate location via SMS. so I used fused location api ... but now I don't know how to incorporate the SMS manager on my current app ... at present I only built a simple app which shows the users current location by pressing a button 
I just want help on how to incorporate SMS manager in my app.
I also want the message to be in a URL form plus the coordinates so that it will be easy for the receiver to track the user.

here is my code Main activity

```
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Looper;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 2300;
TextView textView;
Button sosbtn;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
LocationRequest locationRequest;
LocationCallback locationCallback;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                }


            }

        }

    }


}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    sosbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sosbtn);

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        buildLocationRequest();
        buildLocationCallBack();
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        sosbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
                    return;
                }
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

            }
        });

    }

}

private void buildLocationCallBack() {
    locationCallback= new LocationCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            for(Location location:locationResult.getLocations())
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+"/"+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        }
    };

}

private void buildLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(5);


}
```

}

your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, declare the `location` object as a private field and on the click of your button:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault ();

String message = "My location: https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=" + location.getLatitude () + "," + location.getLongitude ();
String phoneNumber = "+1....";

smsManager.sendTextMessage (phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

The above link should redirect your recipient to google maps.

[SmsManager.sendTextMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Don't forget to add this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

and [request the send sms permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) in runtime.

Comment: sir can you show me how to declare it?  im very new to android programming

Comment: @LJCa-ong below `LocationCallback locationCallback;` add `private Location location;` then on your `onLocationResult`'s `for` loop, assign it to the new value `this.location = location`. I'd suggest you not to skip steps though. Go through a basic Java tutorial to understand OOP, should help you in your Android journey :)

Comment: sir can i ask a favor can you edit it for me ... im still not get it

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow, it's very late here :D

Comment: sir can you help me with this

Comment: @LJCa-ong did you read my first comment? I explained that in there.

Comment: sir i dont how to how to change the value of my 'onlocationResult' can you send me a edited code for that and also for the sms manager don't work.

Comment: sir your my last resort ... please help me

Comment: @LJCa-ong I updated my answer. But it won't obviously be very helpful, as you clearly lack basic knowledge of Java programming and Android. Consider following a course on Java then basic Android.